# 2-Dimensional std::array woes

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stl, stdarray

I thought I liked the idea of std::array from C++11, but it looks like it has some quarks. I found this out because the following code gives a segmentation fault:

```
#include<array>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
        std::array<std::array<int*, 5>, 4> sum;

        //Initialize sum array
        std::cout << sum.size() << " " << sum[0].size() << "\n";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sum.size(); i++) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < sum[0].size(); j++) {
                        if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                                *(sum[i][j]) = 0;
                        else
                                sum[i][j] = nullptr;
                }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
4 5
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

`sum.size()` returns 4, as expected, and `sum[0].size()` returns `5`, as expected; IE it seems like we have an array with 4 rows and 5 columns. However, I get a segmentation fault when I try to execute this program (as shown above). [This link](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2011/10/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c11.html) suggests that reversing the order of the way I access my array (as in change `sum[i][j]` to `sum[j][i]`) should work, but I also get a seg-fault then too. This made me think I might have been doing something wrong with my pointers (I'm a little rusty with my C++), so I changed sum to be an array of integers, so it read as follows:

```
#include<array>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
        std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 4> sum;

        //Initialize sum array
        std::cout << sum.size() << " " << sum[0].size() << "\n";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sum.size(); i++) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < sum[0].size(); j++) {
                        if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                                sum[i][j] = 0; //works as sum[j][i] too!!!
                        else
                                sum[i][j] = 1;

        std::cout << sum[i][j];
                }
     std::cout << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "here\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Which works, and outputs:

```
4 5
00000
01111
01111
01111
here
```

However, I'm confused, because if I switch the `sum[i][j]`'s to `sum[j][i]`'s, it also works and outputs the same thing! I would expect to get a seg-fault when I try `sum[5][0]` during the final iteration of the inner loop the first time that it is run! I am now willing to call myself hella confused. What is going on?

**Extra info:** I am using g++ 4.8.4 with the -std=c++11 flag set.

Comment: You have uninitialized `int*` in your first snippet...

Comment: You should not dereference uninitialized pointers. in the second snippet, it isn't `int*`

Comment: Out of bound access is UB, and *"working"* is a valid UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet doesn't work because you are accessing random memory locations. You declared (essentially) a bidimensional array of (uninitialized) pointers, and in your code you are dereferencing them, which is undefined behavior and very likely to cause a segfault (you are trying to write on random memory locations, which are most likely non mapped in the current virtual address space).

The second snippet is fine; reversing the two indexes is wrong, but you don't get any error because no explicit bound checking is performed by `std::array` (or by the compiler on the underlying C arrays). What happens when you get to the invalid index (4 on the first index) is technically still undefined behavior; in practice, you are probably overwriting unrelated variables on the stack, and the program keeps on going by chance.

Answer (score 1):

```
// This is undefined behavior too
int* array[4][5];
*(array[0][0]) = 0;

// This is also undefined behavior, and for the same reason
int *cell;
*cell = 0;
```

If you want to use the object a pointer points to, you have to make it point at an actual object; e.g. by assigning the address of a valid object to it, or creating a brand new object (e.g. with `new`) and assigning it to the pointer.

Not knowing your ultimate goal, using pointers looked like a very strange design choice; switching to an array of `int` is probably right.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. For the record, I was using int pointers because you can't tell if a regular integer is uninitialized, and I thought I could maybe avoid using a wrapper class by utilizing `nullptr` to identify uninitialized pointers.